# How to handle 3rd party javascript app with cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a question about loading javascript source and initialize function on a page depends on the user`s cookie preference. I have an API that I can check the user's cookie preference with javascript.

My first idea was to hide(with js) the app (which will be loaded on the page via 3rd party script source and initialize function) and show a message to the user that the user can't see the app/content because of his/her cookie setting. But on the legal side, it is allowed because even the user doesn't see the app/content it is going to be loaded on the browser.

My second idea was creating a script tag dynamically and adding in head and run the initialize function,
but in this case, if initialize works faster than script tag creating function, I get an error. And even if it works sometimes user has to reload page couple of times to load the app.

Is there any better practice/idea that you can advise me on?